# Return created_at and updated_at as timestamps in API (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, laravel-5

I need to return `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes in timestamp format but only for my API methods. I don't want to manually loop through results and modify them as I return a lot of relationships so I guess it's not a good way to handle that.

If I set access mutators then everywhere in my app I'll get the dates in timestamps and I'm not sure if that is what I want. Also this is not a good solution since I'll set mutators for each model only because I need to output them in API.

Is there a way to handle that without manually looping through the big response I have and applying `Carbon::parse($value)->timestamp;` to all dates?

Answer (score 1):

How about simply overriding Eloquent's method?

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function serializeDate(\DateTime $date)
{
    return $date->getTimestamp();
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, but it gives me this: Argument 1 passed to serializeDate() must be an instance of App\EloquentModels\DateTime, instance of Carbon\Carbon given.

Comment: Which Laravel's version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1